# how do i overwrite acl.xml for a module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, acl, aclresource

I'm using a module that gives errors for its acl.xml file.
The title for the resources is not set.

Can I fix this with a custom module, and overwrite with the correct values?
How would I do this? I have never used acl before.

this is the acl in question.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource title="Mageplaza Smtp admin" id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource title="Mageplaza Smtp menu" id="Mageplaza_Core::menu">
                    <resource id="Mageplaza_Smtp::smtp" title="Mageplaza Smtp" translate="title" sortOrder="45">
                        <resource id="Mageplaza_Smtp::log" title="Emails Log" translate="title" sortOrder="10"/>
                        <resource id="Mageplaza_Smtp::abandoned_cart" title="Abandoned Cart" translate="title" sortOrder="20"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
                <resource title="Mageplaza Smtp marketing" id="Magento_Backend::marketing">
                    <resource id="Mageplaza_Smtp::email_marketing_menu" title="Email Marketing" sortOrder="20"/>
                </resource>
                <resource title="Mageplaza Smtp stores" id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource title="Mageplaza Smtp stores_settings" id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource title="Mageplaza Smtp config" id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Mageplaza_Smtp::configuration" title="Mageplaza Smtp"/>
                            <resource id="Mageplaza_Smtp::email_marketing" title="Marketing Automation"/>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: can you show the error and acl.xml file for more information?

Comment: On which page do you get the error can you share it with us?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the following exception, my solution will work for you.
[image]

Lets assume this is the `acl.xml` with missing `title`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <!-- Title is missing in the following line -->
                <resource id="Magento_Catalog::catalog" translate="title" sortOrder="30">
                    <resource id="Magento_Catalog::catalog_inventory" title="Inventory" translate="title" sortOrder="10"/>
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Magento_Catalog::config_catalog" title="Catalog Section" translate="title" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_attributes">
                        <resource id="Magento_Catalog::attributes_attributes" title="Product" translate="title" sortOrder="30"/>
                        <resource id="Magento_Catalog::sets" title="Attribute Set" translate="title" sortOrder="40"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Then this `acl.xml` in your custom module should fix the error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Magento_Catalog::catalog" title="Catalog"/>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

Note: If you can provide the `acl.xml`, which throws the error, I can provide the exact solution.

Comment: Hi Ahmad. thank you for your answer. i have added the acl in question.

Comment: @JonasdeHerdt the `acl.xml` has the required titles, however, i noticed you have added the title for `Magento_Backend::admin` resource as well. `Magento_Backend::admin` is a resource which is created by Magento and doesnt need to have a title like this - it already has a title from `vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/acl.xml`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="<Vendor>_<Module>::top_level" title="Module Title" translate="title" sortOrder="10">
                <resource id="<Vendor>_<Module>::sub_level" title="Sub Level" translate="title" sortOrder="10"/>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. You can use CTRL + K to format a code block.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).